# Matlab: How I can make this transformation on the matrix A?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix `A` `4x10000`, I want to use it to find another matrix `C`.

I'll simplify my problem with a simple example:

from a matrix `A`

```
20     4     4    74    20    20     
36     1     1    11    36    36     
77     1     1    15    77    77     
 3     4     2     6     7     8
```

I want, first, to find an intermediate entity B:

```
             2     3     4     6     7    8     

[20 36 77]   0     1     0     0     1    1     3

[4   1  1]   1     0     1     0     0    0     2

[74 11 15]   0     0     0     1     0    0     1
```

we put 1 if the corresponding value of the first line and the vector on the left, made ​​a column in the matrix A.

the last column of the entity B is the sum of 1 of each line.

at the end I want a matrix C, consisting of vectors which are left in the entity B, but only if the sum of 1 is greater than or equal to 2.

for my example:

```
     20  4
C =  36  1
     77  1
```

N.B: for my problem, I use a matrix `A` `4x10000`

Comment: So, the first three rows from A form the lines on the left for forming B?

Comment: And do you need B  or can we directly get C?

Comment: @Divakar: I gave B only to explain what I want to have, but we can directly get C.

Comment: What is a column is repeated in A, that is let's say its column 5 is also `[20 36 77 3]'`?

Comment: @Divakar: the 4th line in A represents events that deliver results, the rest of the column. For my problem, two different events can give the same result, this explains why there are repetitions in A(1:3,:).

Comment: I meant what if the 4th line has common elements too. So if `column5` also has `3` in that 4th line, then it becomes same as `column1`.

Comment: @Divakar: the fourth line may have elements that are repeated, but the columns of A are unique and without repetitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you -

```
%// We need to replace this as its not available in your old version of MATLAB:
%// [unqcols,~,col_match] = unique(A(1:end-1,:).','rows','stable') %//'

A1 = A(1:end-1,:).'; %//'
[unqmat_notinorder,row_ind,labels] = unique(A1,'rows');
[tmp_sortedval,ordered_ind] = sort(row_ind);

unqcols = unqmat_notinorder(ordered_ind,:);

[tmp_matches,col_match] = ismember(labels,ordered_ind);
%// OR use - "[tmp2,col_match] = ismember(A1,out,'rows');"

C = unqcols(sum(bsxfun(@eq,col_match,1:max(col_match)),1)>=2,:).'; %//'
%// OR use - "C = out(accumarray(col_match,ones(1,numel(col_match)))>=2,:).'"
```

Comment: why you stop to v3? I do not always have 3 vectors left in B. It depends on the matrix A. So the number of vk is unknown if A is a matrix with enormous size!

Comment: @bzak What do you mean, stop to v3? I am skipping calculating B and directly getting C.

Comment: If the dimension of A is 4x10000. Does that code will be the same?

Comment: @bzak Maybe the variable names got you confused? Edit with those. Assuming the assumptions set in the question and the comments, I think it should.

Comment: Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.

Comment: @bzak Copy pasted everything from the code? At the end it's `:).'`, which is not smiley, its part of the code, if that's throwing the error at you.

Comment: Yes, I copy pasted evrything from the code. and I get the error

Comment: @bzak Here's a working example - https://ideone.com/o5vZa4 The results are different, I guess because they don't have `unique` with those functionality, but it runs without error. Also, you can count the number of opening and closing parentheses you know.

Comment: I do not know if the problem is caused by my matlab 2009 version!

Comment: @bzak Comeon just count the `opening and closing parentheses`! The counts must be equal! It can't be MATLAB version thing.

Comment: @bzak Check out the code in the edit part? Run and see at which line it throws that error, if it does.

Comment: I think that with my version of matlab, there is a problem with the use of ~

Comment: @bzak Oh I see! So, just put anything to replace that `~`. Thus, do something like `[unqcols,tmp,col_match] = ..`. This should work! Let me know!

Comment: with tmp, I now get the following error: ??? Error using ==> unique at 34
Unrecognized option.

Comment: The problem is solved. Divakar, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @bzak Finally! Awesome! Made few edits to make it clean and maybe better with performance!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
[a,~,c] = unique(A(1:end-1,:).', 'rows', 'stable');
C=a(histc(c,unique(c))>=2, :).';
```

**Edit:** For older versions of MATLAB:

```
D=A(1:end-1,:);
C=unique(D(:,squeeze(sum(all(bsxfun(@eq, D, permute(D, [1 3 2])))))>=2).', 'rows').':
```

Comment: ??? [a,~,c] = unique(A(1:end-1,:).', 'rows', 'stable')
        |
Error: Expression or statement is incorrect--possibly unbalanced (, {, or [.