# Matlab: How I can make this transformation on the matrix A? (part 2)

Tags: matlab, matrix

N.B: This question is more complex than my previous question: [Matlab: How I can make this transformation on the matrix A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26704462/matlab-how-i-can-make-this-transformation-on-the-matrix-a)

I have a matrix `A` `4x10000`, I want to use it to find another matrix `C`, based on a predefined vector U.

I'll simplify my problem with a simple example:

from a matrix `A`

```
20     4     4    74    20    20    4  
36     1     1    11    36    36    1     
77     1     1    15    77    77    1    
 3     4     2     6     7     8   15
```

and

`U=[2  3  4  6  7  8  2&4&15  7&8  4|6]`.

```
& : AND

| : OR
```

I want, first, to find an intermediate entity `B`:

```
               2     3     4     6     7    8     2&4&15    7&8     4|6

[20 36 77]     0     1     0     0     1    1       0        1       0       4

[4   1  1]     1     0     1     0     0    0       1        0       1       4

[74 11 15]     0     0     0     1     0    0       0        0       1       2
```

we put 1 if the corresponding value of the first line and the vector on the left, made ​​a column in the matrix `A`.

the last column of the entity `B` is the sum of 1 of each line.

at the end I want a matrix `C`, consisting of vectors which are left in the entity `B`, but only if the sum of 1 is greater than or equal to 3.

for my example:

```
     20  4
C =  36  1
     77  1
```

Comment: how big can A and U grow?

Comment: I think you need to represent U in this form: `U={2  3  4  6  7  8  [2 4 15]  [7 8]  4 6}`. Then use a `for` loop to check for exhaustive combinations. By representing U in such a form will help you to model the `&` and `|`.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: A dimension is 4x10000, and U is 1x80.

Comment: How do you save `U`, as a string? I mean you have written `&` and `|`. How do you input them in MATLAB? Or is that we have to figure out?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar: I do not know how to represent them with matlab, but I wish I could put the vector U in a similar form to facilitate the writing of the vector U for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a complex one indeed and because of the many restrictions and *labeling* processes involved, it won't be as efficient as the solution to the previous problem. Here's the code to solve the posted problem -

```
find_labels1 = 2:8; %// Labels to be detected - main block
find_labels2 = {[2 4 15],[7 8],[4 6]}; %// ... side block
A1 = A(1:end-1,:); %// all of A except the last row
A2 = A(end,:); %// last row of A

%// Find unique columns and their labels for all of A execpt the last row
[unqmat_notinorder,row_ind,inv_labels] = unique(A1.','rows'); %//'
[tmp_sortedval,ordered_ind] = sort(row_ind);
unqcols = unqmat_notinorder(ordered_ind,:);
[tmp_matches,labels] = ismember(inv_labels,ordered_ind);

%// Assign labels to each group
ctl = numel(unique(labels));
labelgrp = arrayfun(@(x) find(labels==x),1:ctl,'un',0);

%// Work for the main comparisons
matches = bsxfun(@eq,A2,find_labels1'); %//'
maincols = zeros(ctl,numel(find_labels1));
for k = 1:ctl
    maincols(k,:) = any(matches(:,labelgrp{k}),2);
end

%// Work for the extra comparisons added that made this problem extra-complex
lens = cellfun('length',find_labels2);
lens(end) = 1;
extcols = nan(ctl,numel(find_labels2));
for k = 1:numel(find_labels2)
    idx = find(ismember(A2,find_labels2{k}));
    extcols(:,k)=arrayfun(@(n) sum(ismember(labelgrp{n},idx))>=lens(k),1:ctl).'; %//'
end
C = unqcols(sum([maincols extcols],2)>=3,:).' %//'# Finally the output
```

Comment: thank you very very much Divakar :). I have a question! Where I can see & and | in your answer?

Comment: @bzak That's in the **%// Work for the extra comparisons** part section. So, for that part I am using `find_labels2` for comparisons and the operation is decided by `lens`, which is `[3 2 1]`. So, with the code `>=lens(k)`, it means it needs at least three matches for the first comparison of [2 4 15], at least two comparison for [7 8] and any one comparison for [4 6], even though [4 6] is of length 2. Not sure if this would explain the essence of it to you but that's what's going on there.

Comment: @bzak If it were `4&6`, I would have kept the `lens` as `[3 2 2]`. So `&` would mean I am keeping the lengths of the numeric arrays being calculated with `cellfun('length'.)` and `|` would be when I set it to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a partial answer. I think you can take from here. Idea is to concatenate first 3 rows of `A` with each element of `U` replicated as last column. After you get the 3D matrix, replicate your original `A` and then just compare the rows. The rows which are equal, that is equivalent to putting `one` in your table.

```
B=(A(1:3,:).';
B1=repmat(B,[1 1 length(U)]);
C=permute(U,[3 1 2]);
D=repmat(C,[size(B1,1),1,1]);
E=[B1 D];
F=repmat(A',[1 1 size(E,3)]);
```

Now compare F and E, row-wise. If the rows are equal, then you put 1 in your table. For replicating `&` and `|`, you can form some kind of indicator vector.

Say,

```
indU=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 7 7 8 8 -9 -9];
```

Same positive value indicates `&`, same negative value indicates `|`. Different value indicate different entries.

I hope you can take from here.